# Voice Recognition in Android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

i want to record some words using my app and i want to match whenever i speak that same words again. how can i achieve that? i have also seen this tutorial...

http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-implement-voice-recognition-a-nice-easy-tutorial/

but its for speech to text. whatever you speak it goes to the google server and shows the list of words similar to what you have spoken. but i need to record some words and match when ever i speak again.

any suggestion, tips or tutorial will be really appreciative and i,ll be really grateful to that.

P.S i want this without internet.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a feature extraction part and DTW algorithm for matching of feature vectors of the arbitrary length.

To extract features you can use exsisting ASR toolkit like CMUSphinx http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net

To match features with DTW you need to write simple function, see

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping

Read this thread about similar implementation

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/forums/forum/382337/topic/2348240